# Matrix multiplication of inverse and non-inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

I just want to ask why $A^{-1} B^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1}$ but not $AB = BA$? Aren't the two essentially the same? Why are they different? Also what does $(A + B)^{-1}$ essentially equal to? I know that it is not $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$. Thanks!

Comment: Are you thinking of $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ perhaps?

Comment: Ah, yes. You're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the initial relation incorrectly, it is $$(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$$

The reason it's true is that $$AB(B^{-1}A^{-1})=A(BB^{-1})A^{-1}=AIA^{-1}=I$$

Hence $B^{-1}A^{-1}$ is something you can multiply by $AB$ to get the identity.  That is the definition of $(AB)^{-1}$.

---

Second question: $(A+B)^{-1}$ is generally unrelated to $A,B,A^{-1}$, and $B^{-1}$.  For example, consider $A=I, B=-I$.  Then $A+B=0$, and $(A+B)^{-1}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: But AB != BA in general, right? Does this mean that taking the inverse totally changes the properties of the matrices?

Comment: No, it means that taking the inverse reverses order in some sense.  Similarly $(ABCD)^{-1}=D^{-1}C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

Comment: So (ABCD)^-1 != A^-1 B^-1 C^-1 D^-1?

Comment: Correct, there is only one correct way to order $A^{-1}, B^{-1}, C^{-1}, D^{-1}$>

Answer (score 1):

If $A^{-1}B^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ Then, taking inverses of both sides, $(A^{-1}B^{-1})^{-1}=(B^{-1}A^{-1})^{-1}$ or $(B^{-1})^{-1}(A^{-1})^{-1}=(A^{-1})^{-1}(B^{-1})^{-1}$ so $BA=AB$.  The same argument works in reverse as well so the statements $A^{-1}B^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ and $BA=AB$ are the same if A and B are invertable.

Comment: Which does not hold true, right?

Comment: The statement $BA=AB$ does not hold true in general.